# Multiple execution of statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just trying a random thing to clear my doubt but when I ran the code below the printing() function executes 2 times, can someone explain to me why the printing function executes 2 times.

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  printing() {
    print("printing");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    printing();            //calling printing() function
    return Container();
  }
}
```

op(in console):

printing
printing

Answer (score 1):

You should run your app in debug mode to understand what happens because there is no reason that your `printing` method is called twice.

I have tested your example and I have only one `printing` output in my console